# Add special character in PHP

Tags: php, database, special-characters

My database don't store $title with particular characters. What can I do? Below my php code:

```
    <?php
require "init.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$author = $_POST["author"];
$urlImage = $_POST["urlImage"];

preg_match("/^[\p{L}\p{N} '.-]+$/", $title);
$sql_query = "insert into user_info_book values('$user_name', '$title', '$author', '$urlImage');";
?>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use prepared statements (recommended, but requires MySQLi or PDO, the old `mysql_` doesn't have this), or escape your input with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` / `mysql_real_escape_string()` depending on your chosen API.

Comment: with $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title); the string title doesn't appear in database

Comment: What kind of API do you use? `mysql_`, `mysqli_` or PDO? Show the code relevant for the query as well as the connection.

Comment: $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($title); I'm sorry. I use mysqli but doesn't work

Comment: If you're using `mysqli_`, you really should use prepared statements instead. However, `mysqli_real_escape_string` requires two parameters, the first being the connection, the second being the string. `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $title);` (where `$conn` is your connection object).

Comment: yeahhhhhh. Now It works. Post your answer and I'll vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special characters can break your SQL query, so to deal with that, either use prepared statements or use the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function.

The `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function requires two parameters, the first one being the connection object, the second being the string to be escaped, an example below

```
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $title);
```

However, a better approach would be to use prepared statements instead. An example of this is given below

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info_book VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $user_name, $title, $author, $urlImage);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    // echo mysqli_error($DB_H); // Errors should only be shown in development
}
```

Everywhere in the code, `$conn` is the connection object you already created.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
```

[mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)  Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.

Comment: with $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title); the string title doesn't appear in database

Comment: @carlo can you provide some sample data.

Comment: one example of title is "Contro l'intercultura"